# Website going in and out, no activities shown for past 3 days on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, web

Our website (hosted on Azure) has been going in and out the whole morning, works for 5 minutes and then stops loading, then switches back on again. Here's the error message I receive. I've tried restarting the site from Azure Web App a few times and the problem persists.

I've also track activities on Azure dashboard and there is nothing recorded for the last 3 days.

http://i60.tinypic.com/mie6v5.png

Please let me know how to fix this issue, thanks.

P.S.: We have a Standard subscription, and I'm thinking this might be due to the Service Bus - West US and Australia Southeast - Partial Service Interruption as reported on http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current

Comment: does it looks like it takes a while to load again after a long period of inactivity?

Comment: Try if it is not consuming so many processing time. What hosting plan ae you using? Remember that Free/Shared plans have limited resources, if you consume allt hat, even if only one access, you site will be outed.

Comment: As they already suggested, check your Tier. If that is not the issue, scale your website to Standard and let it run for a bit of time there, then scale back to the previous tier. Lastly, make sure an application update didn't do something weird, 3 days ago. If the problem persists, contact support.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because you are using the Free tier which limits CPU to 5 min per hour or Shared which is slightly higher. To keep your site up and responsive, enable Always On in the site's configure tab. You will need to scale your site to the Basic or Standard tier first.

I would also recommend using End Point Monitoring to verify your site is actively handling requests. You can set this in the configure tab as well.

Lastly, I recommend you use the /support tool in Kudu as it provides a richer set of graphs to monitor site activity. To access it type in this URL in your browser, https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/support where mysite is the name of your site. Best of all is this tool can analyze your site as well and help you troubleshoot issues.

Hope that is helpful.